# Laravel Ajax request, Auth:login returns false! but user is logged in after refresh

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I want to log users in with ajax request and after login in controller, redirect users to dashboard with javascript.

The Problem is when I use `Auth:login($user)` in controller, it returns false and my `return` line in controller is not reached.  when I refresh the page manually I see that user is logged in !!

Backend (pseudo code):

```
    $r = $request->all();
    $user = User::where('email', $r['email'])->first();

    Auth::login($user);  // this returns false


    return [  // this line is not reached
        'status' > 'success'
    ];
```

Front End :

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'Post',
       url: '/login/js-login',
       data: user_data,
       success: function (res) {
        if (res.data.status == 'success') {
         toastr.success(" LoginSuccessfull!")                             
         window.location.replace("https://www.example.com");
      } else {
         toastr.error('Error Login!')
      }

      });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that you are using `Auth::login` in `api.php` which is stateless.

Either you need to use Token base authentication or use `Auth::login` in `web.php` which is `statefull`

If you are using laravel version `< 5.3` then middleware should be `web` not `api`

`Auth:logn` returns `void` so you can use

```
Auth::login($user);
return [
    'status' => Auth:check()
];
```

`check()` Determine if the current user is authenticated.

Comment: I am using `routes.php` ,  I want to know if its possible to log in users  inside controller based on an ajax request and then refresh the page with `js` so user see himself logged in!?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki : What middleware you are using , middleware should be `web` ?

Comment: Yes it is web !

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki : then share what you get in `return dd($user); ` ? you are not getting user object

Comment: I have tested lots of time and debugged, `$user`  object is found and available,   when i refresh the page manually , user is logged in, it means `Auth:login()`  is worked !!   but I dont want it to return somthing befor my `return["status"=>"success"]`

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki : `Auth:logn` return `void` means nothing no `true` no `false`

Comment: I know , I have checked Laravel vendor, Its very wierd,  befor that i used `loginUsingId($user->id)`  that returns true or false, exactly the same results for `login()`

Comment: result of `dd($user)` : `User {#630  #fillable: array:8 [    0 => "email"    1 => "password"    2 => "username"    3 => "is_active"    4 => "api_token"    5 => "autologin_token"    6 => "commission"    7 => "access"  ]  +sortable: array:2 [    0 => "id"    1 => "access"  ]  ...........`

Comment: Try updated `Auth::login($user);
return [
    'status' => Auth:check()
];`

Comment: I'll try,  Forgot to tell that user in DB does not have any password.  I considered it empty

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki : no need of password for `Auth::login()`

Comment: I am very sorry, this was my mistake :  `return ["status" > "success"]`,   But I should get syntax error! not `false`

Comment: yup, i am at the `api.php`, transferring it to `web.php` solved the problem. thank you! `[+1]`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `loginUsingId`:

```
 $r = $request->all();
    $user = User::where('email', $r['email'])->first();
    if(isset($user)){
        Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
        return ['status' => 'success'];  
    }
    return ['status' => 'fail'];
```

Comment: also tryed `loginUsingId`, same result

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki use dd($user) and see whats in it

Comment: result of `dd($user)` : `User {#630  #fillable: array:8 [    0 => "email"    1 => "password"    2 => "username"    3 => "is_active"    4 => "api_token"    5 => "autologin_token"    6 => "commission"    7 => "access"  ]  +sortable: array:2 [    0 => "id"    1 => "access"  ]  ...........`

Comment: I am very sorry, this was my mistake :  `return ["status" > "success"]`,   But I should get syntax error! not `false`